# Android Navigation: Conditional starting screen in subgraph

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have a `navigation_graph_main.xml` and want to navigate to a subgraph `transaction_graph.xml`. Inside the transaction graph, I have references to `CreateIncomeTransactionFragment` and `CreateTransferTransactionFragment`. Depending on a button clicked within a fragment of `navigation_graph_main.xml`, I want to navigate to either `CreateIncomeTransactionFragment` or `CreateTransferTransactionFragment`.

Is there a way to conditionally choose the starting point of `transaction_graph.xml` before any of the two fragments `CreateIncomeTransactionFragment` or `CreateTransferTransactionFragment` is created?

I tried to see whether it is somehow possible to get access to the backstack or the nav arguments within the fragment that holds the navhost, but that doesn't seem to work as my break point in `onCreate()` never gets triggered.